# install istioctl 1.4.0 is throwing "error: chart metadata (Chart.yaml) missing"

Tags: istio

I am new to Isitio, i try to do an installation on azure K8s and i get the following error using the command **istioctl manifest apply --set profile=demo --logtostderr**

error: chart metadata (Chart.yaml) missing

```
ReadProfileYAML for profile name: demo
2019-11-25T10:48:44.373905Z     info    Loading values from compiled in VFS at path profiles\demo.yaml
2019-11-25T10:48:44.375899Z     info    ReadProfileYAML for profile name: default
2019-11-25T10:48:44.375899Z     info    Loading values from compiled in VFS at path profiles\default.yaml
2019-11-25T10:48:44.475657Z     info    Failed to generate and apply manifests, error: failed to generate manifest: failed to create Istio control plane with spec:
default_namespace:"istio-system" traffic_management:<enabled:<BoolValue:<value:true > > components:<pilot:<enabled:<BoolValue:<value:true > > k8s:<env:<name:"POD_NAME" valueFrom:<fieldRef:<apiVersion:"v1" fieldPath:"metadata.name" > > > env:<name:"POD_NAMESPACE" valueFrom:<fieldRef:<apiVersion:"v1" fieldPath:"metadata.namespace" > > > env:<name:"GODEBUG" value:"gctrace=1" > env:<name:"PILOT_TRACE_SAMPLING" value:"100" > env:<name:"CONFIG_NAMESPACE" value:"istio-config" > hpa_spec:<scaleTargetRef:<kind:"Deployment" name:"istio-pilot" apiVersion:"apps/v1" > minReplicas:1 maxReplicas:5 metrics:<type:"Resource" resource:<name:"cpu" targetAverageUtilization:80 > > > readiness_probe:<httpGet:<path:"/ready" port:<IntOrString:<type:0 intVal:8080 > > > initialDelaySeconds:5 timeoutSeconds:5 periodSeconds:30 > resources:<requests:<key:"cpu" value:"10m" > requests:<key:"memory" value:"100Mi" > > strategy:<rollingUpdate:<maxUnavailable:<IntOrString:<type:1 strVal:"25%" > > maxSurge:<IntOrString:<type:1 strVal:"100%" > > > > > > > > policy:<enabled:<BoolValue:<value:true > > components:<policy:<enabled:<BoolValue:<value:true > > k8s:<env:<name:"POD_NAMESPACE" valueFrom:<fieldRef:<apiVersion:"v1" fieldPath:"metadata.namespace" > > > hpa_spec:<scaleTargetRef:<kind:"Deployment" name:"istio-policy" apiVersion:"apps/v1" > minReplicas:1 maxReplicas:5 metrics:<type:"Resource" resource:<name:"cpu" targetAverageUtilization:80 > > > resources:<requests:<key:"cpu" value:"10m" > requests:<key:"memory" value:"100Mi" > > strategy:<rollingUpdate:<maxUnavailable:<IntOrString:<type:1 strVal:"25%" > > maxSurge:<IntOrString:<type:1 strVal:"100%" > > > > > > > > telemetry:<enabled:<BoolValue:<value:true > > components:<telemetry:<enabled:<BoolValue:<value:true > > k8s:<env:<name:"POD_NAMESPACE" valueFrom:<fieldRef:<apiVersion:"v1" fieldPath:"metadata.namespace" > > > env:<name:"GOMAXPROCS" value:"6" > hpa_spec:<scaleTargetRef:<kind:"Deployment" name:"istio-telemetry" apiVersion:"apps/v1" > minReplicas:1 maxReplicas:5 metrics:<type:"Resource" resource:<name:"cpu" targetAverageUtilization:80 > > > replica_count:1 resources:<limits:<key:"cpu" value:"4800m" > limits:<key:"memory" value:"4G" > requests:<key:"cpu" value:"50m" > requests:<key:"memory" value:"100Mi" > > strategy:<rollingUpdate:<maxUnavailable:<IntOrString:<type:1 strVal:"25%" > > maxSurge:<IntOrString:<type:1 strVal:"100%" > > > > > > > > security:<enabled:<BoolValue:<value:true > > components:<citadel:<enabled:<BoolValue:<value:true > > k8s:<strategy:<rollingUpdate:<maxUnavailable:<IntOrString:<type:1 strVal:"25%" > > maxSurge:<IntOrString:<type:1 strVal:"100%" > > > > > > cert_manager:<enabled:<BoolValue:<> > > node_agent:<enabled:<BoolValue:<> > > > > config_management:<enabled:<BoolValue:<value:true > > components:<galley:<enabled:<BoolValue:<value:true > > k8s:<replica_count:1 resources:<requests:<key:"cpu" value:"100m" > > strategy:<rollingUpdate:<maxUnavailable:<IntOrString:<type:1 strVal:"25%" > > maxSurge:<IntOrString:<type:1 strVal:"100%" > > > > > > > > auto_injection:<enabled:<BoolValue:<value:true > > components:<injector:<enabled:<BoolValue:<value:true > > k8s:<replica_count:1 strategy:<rollingUpdate:<maxUnavailable:<IntOrString:<type:1 strVal:"25%" > > maxSurge:<IntOrString:<type:1 strVal:"100%" > > > > > > > > gateways:<enabled:<BoolValue:<value:true > > components:<ingress_gateway:<enabled:<BoolValue:<value:true > > k8s:<hpa_spec:<scaleTargetRef:<kind:"Deployment" name:"istio-ingressgateway" apiVersion:"apps/v1" > minReplicas:1 maxReplicas:5 metrics:<type:"Resource" resource:<name:"cpu" targetAverageUtilization:80 > > > resources:<limits:<key:"cpu" value:"2000m" > limits:<key:"memory" value:"1024Mi" > requests:<key:"cpu" value:"10m" > requests:<key:"memory" value:"40Mi" > > strategy:<rollingUpdate:<maxUnavailable:<IntOrString:<type:1 strVal:"25%" > > maxSurge:<IntOrString:<type:1 strVal:"100%" > > > > > > egress_gateway:<enabled:<BoolValue:<value:true > > k8s:<hpa_spec:<scaleTargetRef:<kind:"Deployment" name:"istio-egressgateway" apiVersion:"apps/v1" > minReplicas:1 maxReplicas:5 metrics:<type:"Resource" resource:<name:"cpu" targetAverageUtilization:80 > > > resources:<limits:<key:"cpu" value:"2000m" > limits:<key:"memory" value:"1024Mi" > requests:<key:"cpu" value:"10m" > requests:<key:"memory" value:"40Mi" > > strategy:<rollingUpdate:<maxUnavailable:<IntOrString:<type:1 strVal:"25%" > > maxSurge:<IntOrString:<type:1 strVal:"100%" > > > > > > > > cni:<enabled:<BoolValue:<> > > values:<key:"certmanager" value:map[hub:quay.io/jetstack image:cert-manager-controller tag:v0.6.2] > values:<key:"clusterResources" value:true > values:<key:"galley" value:map[enableAnalysis:false image:galley] > values:<key:"gateways" value:map[istio-egressgateway:map[autoscaleEnabled:false env:map[ISTIO_META_ROUTER_MODE:sni-dnat] ports:[map[name:http2 port:80] map[name:https port:443] map[name:tls port:15443 targetPort:15443]] secretVolumes:[map[mountPath:/etc/istio/egressgateway-certs name:egressgateway-certs secretName:istio-egressgateway-certs] map[mountPath:/etc/istio/egressgateway-ca-certs name:egressgateway-ca-certs secretName:istio-egressgateway-ca-certs]] type:ClusterIP zvpn:map[enabled:true suffix:global]] istio-ingressgateway:map[applicationPorts: autoscaleEnabled:false debug:info domain: env:map[ISTIO_META_ROUTER_MODE:sni-dnat] meshExpansionPorts:[map[name:tcp-pilot-grpc-tls port:15011 targetPort:15011] map[name:tcp-citadel-grpc-tls port:8060 targetPort:8060] map[name:tcp-dns-tls port:853 targetPort:853]] ports:[map[name:status-port port:15020 targetPort:15020] map[name:http2 port:80 targetPort:80] map[name:https port:443] map[name:kiali port:15029 targetPort:15029] map[name:prometheus port:15030 targetPort:15030] map[name:grafana port:15031 targetPort:15031] map[name:tracing port:15032 targetPort:15032] map[name:tls port:15443 targetPort:15443]] sds:map[enabled:false image:node-agent-k8s resources:map[limits:map[cpu:2000m memory:1024Mi] requests:map[cpu:100m memory:128Mi]]] secretVolumes:[map[mountPath:/etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs name:ingressgateway-certs secretName:istio-ingressgateway-certs] map[mountPath:/etc/istio/ingressgateway-ca-certs name:ingressgateway-ca-certs secretName:istio-ingressgateway-ca-certs]] type:LoadBalancer zvpn:map[enabled:true suffix:global]]] > values:<key:"global" value:map[arch:map[amd64:2 ppc64le:2 s390x:2] certificates:[] configValidation:true controlPlaneSecurityEnabled:false defaultNodeSelector:map[] defaultPodDisruptionBudget:map[enabled:true] defaultResources:map[requests:map[cpu:10m]] disablePolicyChecks:false enableHelmTest:false enableTracing:true imagePullPolicy:IfNotPresent imagePullSecrets:[] k8sIngress:map[enableHttps:false enabled:false gatewayName:ingressgateway] localityLbSetting:map[enabled:true] logAsJson:false logging:map[level:default:info] meshExpansion:map[enabled:false useILB:false] meshNetworks:map[] mtls:map[auto:false enabled:false] multiCluster:map[clusterName: enabled:false] network: omitSidecarInjectorConfigMap:false oneNamespace:false operatorManageWebhooks:false outboundTrafficPolicy:map[mode:ALLOW_ANY] policyCheckFailOpen:false priorityClassName: proxy:map[accessLogEncoding:TEXT accessLogFile:/dev/stdout accessLogFormat: autoInject:enabled clusterDomain:cluster.local componentLogLevel:misc:error concurrency:2 dnsRefreshRate:300s enableCoreDump:false envoyAccessLogService:map[enabled:false host:<nil> port:<nil>] envoyMetricsService:map[enabled:false host:<nil> port:<nil> tcpKeepalive:map[interval:10s probes:3 time:10s] tlsSettings:map[caCertificates:<nil> clientCertificate:<nil> mode:DISABLE privateKey:<nil> sni:<nil> subjectAltNames:[]]] envoyStatsd:map[enabled:false host:<nil> port:<nil>] excludeIPRanges: excludeInboundPorts: excludeOutboundPorts: image:proxyv2 includeIPRanges:* includeInboundPorts:* kubevirtInterfaces: logLevel:warning privileged:false protocolDetectionTimeout:100ms readinessFailureThreshold:30 readinessInitialDelaySeconds:1 readinessPeriodSeconds:2 resources:map[limits:map[cpu:2000m memory:1024Mi] requests:map[cpu:10m memory:40Mi]] statusPort:15020 tracer:zipkin] proxy_init:map[image:proxyv2 resources:map[limits:map[cpu:100m memory:50Mi] requests:map[cpu:10m memory:10Mi]]] sds:map[enabled:false token:map[aud:istio-ca] udsPath:] tracer:map[datadog:map[address:$(HOST_IP):8126] lightstep:map[accessToken: address: cacertPath: secure:true] zipkin:map[address:]] trustDomain:cluster.local useMCP:true] > values:<key:"grafana" value:map[accessMode:ReadWriteMany contextPath:/grafana dashboardProviders:map[dashboardproviders.yaml:map[apiVersion:1 providers:[map[disableDeletion:false folder:istio name:istio options:map[path:/var/lib/grafana/dashboards/istio] orgId:1 type:file]]]] datasources:map[datasources.yaml:map[apiVersion:1 datasources:<nil>]] enabled:true env:map[] envSecrets:map[] image:map[repository:grafana/grafana tag:6.4.3] ingress:map[annotations:<nil> enabled:false hosts:[grafana.local] tls:<nil>] nodeSelector:map[] persist:false podAntiAffinityLabelSelector:[] podAntiAffinityTermLabelSelector:[] replicaCount:1 security:map[enabled:false passphraseKey:passphrase secretName:grafana usernameKey:username] service:map[annotations:map[] externalPort:3000 loadBalancerIP:<nil> loadBalancerSourceRanges:<nil> name:http type:ClusterIP] storageClassName: tolerations:[]] > values:<key:"istiocoredns" value:map[coreDNSImage:coredns/coredns coreDNSPluginImage:istio/coredns-plugin:0.2-istio-1.1 coreDNSTag:1.6.2 enabled:false] > values:<key:"kiali" value:map[contextPath:/kiali createDemoSecret:true dashboard:map[grafanaURL:<nil> jaegerURL:<nil> passphraseKey:passphrase secretName:kiali usernameKey:username viewOnlyMode:false] enabled:true hub:quay.io/kiali ingress:map[annotations:<nil> enabled:false hosts:[kiali.local] tls:<nil>] nodeSelector:map[] podAntiAffinityLabelSelector:[] podAntiAffinityTermLabelSelector:[] prometheusNamespace:<nil> replicaCount:1 security:map[cert_file:/kiali-cert/cert-chain.pem enabled:false private_key_file:/kiali-cert/key.pem] tag:v1.9] > values:<key:"mixer" value:map[adapters:map[kubernetesenv:map[enabled:true] prometheus:map[enabled:true metricsExpiryDuration:10m] stackdriver:map[auth:map[apiKey: appCredentials:false serviceAccountPath:] enabled:false tracer:map[enabled:false sampleProbability:1]] stdio:map[enabled:true outputAsJson:false] useAdapterCRDs:false] policy:map[adapters:map[kubernetesenv:map[enabled:true] useAdapterCRDs:false] autoscaleEnabled:false image:mixer sessionAffinityEnabled:false] telemetry:map[autoscaleEnabled:false image:mixer loadshedding:map[latencyThreshold:100ms mode:enforce] nodeSelector:map[] podAntiAffinityLabelSelector:[] podAntiAffinityTermLabelSelector:[] replicaCount:1 reportBatchMaxEntries:100 reportBatchMaxTime:1s sessionAffinityEnabled:false tolerations:[] useMCP:true]] > values:<key:"nodeagent" value:map[image:node-agent-k8s] > values:<key:"pilot" value:map[appNamespaces:[] autoscaleEnabled:false autoscaleMax:5 autoscaleMin:1 configMap:true configNamespace:istio-config cpu:map[targetAverageUtilization:80] deploymentLabels:<nil> enableProtocolSniffingForInbound:false enableProtocolSniffingForOutbound:true env:map[] image:pilot ingress:map[ingressClass:istio ingressControllerMode:OFF ingressService:istio-ingressgateway] keepaliveMaxServerConnectionAge:30m meshNetworks:map[networks:map[]] nodeSelector:map[] podAntiAffinityLabelSelector:[] podAntiAffinityTermLabelSelector:[] policy:map[enabled:false] replicaCount:1 tolerations:[] traceSampling:1 useMCP:true] > values:<key:"prometheus" value:map[contextPath:/prometheus enabled:true hub:docker.io/prom ingress:map[annotations:<nil> enabled:false hosts:[prometheus.local] tls:<nil>] nodeSelector:map[] podAntiAffinityLabelSelector:[] podAntiAffinityTermLabelSelector:[] replicaCount:1 retention:6h scrapeInterval:15s security:map[enabled:true] tag:v2.12.0 tolerations:[]] > values:<key:"security" value:map[dnsCerts:map[istio-pilot-service-account.istio-control:istio-pilot.istio-control] enableNamespacesByDefault:true image:citadel selfSigned:true trustDomain:cluster.local] > values:<key:"sidecarInjectorWebhook" value:map[enableNamespacesByDefault:false image:sidecar_injector injectLabel:istio-injection objectSelector:map[autoInject:true enabled:false] rewriteAppHTTPProbe:false selfSigned:false] > values:<key:"telemetry" value:map[enabled:true v2:map[enabled:false]] > values:<key:"tracing" value:map[enabled:true ingress:map[annotations:<nil> enabled:false hosts:<nil> tls:<nil>] jaeger:map[accessMode:ReadWriteMany hub:docker.io/jaegertracing memory:map[max_traces:50000] persist:false spanStorageType:badger storageClassName: tag:1.14] nodeSelector:map[] opencensus:map[exporters:map[stackdriver:map[enable_tracing:true]] hub:docker.io/omnition resources:map[limits:map[cpu:1 memory:2Gi] requests:map[cpu:200m memory:400Mi]] tag:0.1.9] podAntiAffinityLabelSelector:[] podAntiAffinityTermLabelSelector:[] provider:jaeger service:map[annotations:map[] externalPort:9411 name:http-query type:ClusterIP] zipkin:map[hub:docker.io/openzipkin javaOptsHeap:700 maxSpans:500000 node:map[cpus:2] probeStartupDelay:200 queryPort:9411 resources:map[limits:map[cpu:300m memory:900Mi] requests:map[cpu:150m memory:900Mi]] tag:2.14.2]] > values:<key:"version" value: > profile:"demo" hub:"docker.io/istio" tag:"1.4.0"
error: chart metadata (Chart.yaml) missing
```

Any idea from where it could come from ?

Comment: Hi, have You tried following pre-installation instructions for [azure](https://istio.io/docs/setup/platform-setup/azure/) platform?

Comment: I believe this is an issue on windows for the new istioctl installation method. See https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/19020 for more info. We are hoping to have a patch out soon

Comment: went through Helm at the end...